# In Eclipse why Seam classes are not visible when the Seam Facet is enabled?

Tags: eclipse, richfaces, seam, jboss-tools

I am trying to use `Seam 2.2` with my application but cannot see them. This is what I did:

I am working with Java 1.7, Eclipse Luna and Wildfly 8.2.1.

I am working with an enterprise application which consist of: 
* 1 "Enterprise Application Project" named **MyEar**.
* 1 "Dynamic Web Project" named **MyWeb**. Dynamic Web Module is 2.5.
* 1 "EJB Project" named **MyEjb**. EJB Module is 2.1.
* 1 "EJB Client Project" named **MyEjbClient**. 
* 1 "Utility Project" named **MySrc**.

I wanted to use `Seam 2.2`. I know first I have to enable `JSF` before I can enable `Seam`.

---

So I selected the **MyWeb** project, went to its `Project Facets`, enable `JSF 2.2` and save it. This I believe make my project ready to use `JSF`.

Eclipse added `faces-config.xml` file in `WebContent/WEB-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

Eclipse also add these changes to `web.xml`.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

Then again I selected the **MyWeb** project, went to its `Project Facets`, enable `Seam 2.2` and save it. This I believe make my project ready to use `Seam`.

Eclipse created `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` folder.

Eclipse also add these changes to `web.xml`:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
  </security-constraint>
```

---

Now in **MyWeb** project, I create a class. In it I want to define an instance variable of type `HtmlDropDownMenu` which comes with `Seam`:

```
package com.srh.seam.menu;

public class WebMenu {

    HtmlDropDownMenu menu;

}
```

But Eclipse could not find the class `HtmlDropDownMenu` and give me this error message:

> HtmlDropDownMenu cannot be resolved to a type

Class `HtmlDropDownMenu` is in `org.richfaces.component.html` package. Eclipse cannot see the `org.richfaces` package.

What have I done wrong that Eclipse cannot see the `Seam` classes?

Comment: These libraries will not work together, Seam 2.2 will only work with JSF 1.2 and Seam 2.3 will work with JSF 2.2...you are better running on JBoss AS 7 rather than Wildfly, Seam stopped development a few years ago

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the corresponding richfaces jars are in your MyWeb/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.